# NullPointerException on a Map in java. What is wrong?

Tags: java, file, dictionary, nullpointerexception

I am trying to load a file into a Map with a method as below:

```
private static Map<String,Integer> indexVocabulary;
public static Map<String,Integer> getVocabularyFromFile() throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(VOCABULARY_FILE);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));      
    String line;
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
    {
        LOG.debug(line);
        String[] kv = line.split(" ");
        LOG.debug(kv[0]);
        LOG.debug(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(kv[1])));


        indexVocabulary.put(kv[0], Integer.parseInt(kv[1]));
    }
    return indexVocabulary;
}
```

I can see output from `line`'also from `kv[0],kv[1]` and `Integer.parseInt(kv[1])` However I get a NullPointerException  on the line `indexVocabulary.put(kv[0], Integer.parseInt(kv[1]));` Does anyone know what is wrong with this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't initialize `indexVocabulary`, so it's `null`.

Change

```
private static Map<String,Integer> indexVocabulary;
```

to

```
private static Map<String,Integer> indexVocabulary = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't initialize your Map, it's just an empty variable. You need to instantiate a Map, for example you can do:

```
indexVocabulary = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize your `indexVocabulary`.

Just do:

```
indexVocabulary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not assigning any object to `indexVocabulary`, so it is null. Just declare it like this:

```
private static Map<String,Integer> indexVocabulary = new HashMap<String,Integer>;
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't instantiated your map. So simply put

`indexVocabulary = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`